# Loading GPGS Leaderboard breaks App

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-games

I am using Libgdx.  I am trying to add a leaderboard to my game using Google Play Game Services.  I have an ActionResolver interface with the the abstract methods.  The submitscoreGPGS() method isn't breaking the app at all.  But when I add the getLeaderboard() the game wont even load in my Android emulator. It just says Platformer has stopped working.

This is what detects if the play has hit the leaderboards button.  Touched.inBounds is just a utility method that I have made.

```
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

        //some code removed

        //if I comment this if statement the app will run just fine
        if(Touched.inBounds(leaderboardButton.bounds, camera) && paused) {

            game.actionResolver.getLeaderboardGPGS();

        }

    }
```

This is my AndroidLauncher class

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements ActionResolver {

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
int REQUEST_LEADERBOARD = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new Platformer(this), config);

}

@Override
public void submitScoreGPGS(int score) {

    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), score);

}

@Override
public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {

    startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.leaderboard_id)), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);

}
}
```

Logcat error:

```
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 84
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): Process: com.JrodManU.Platformer.android, PID: 1203
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient parameter is required.
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.fq.b(Unknown Source)
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.c(Unknown Source)
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.LeaderboardsImpl.submitScore(Unknown Source)
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.LeaderboardsImpl.submitScore(Unknown Source)
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.JrodManU.Platformer.android.AndroidLauncher.submitScoreGPGS(AndroidLauncher.java:41)
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.JrodManU.Platformer.GameScreen.logicUpdate(GameScreen.java:109)
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.JrodManU.Platformer.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:55)
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:416)
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
12-26 13:46:23.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
12-26 13:46:27.735: E/AndroidGraphics(1203): waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
```

Comment: Post your logcat trace; this is the easiest way to start diagnosing  the issue(s) that is causing the application to break.

Comment: You didn't initialize your mGoogleApiClient. https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html